# Loading constants from a web-service without using resolve or manually bootstrapping the app

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am working on a small piece of an angular project and need to define some constants that are derived from values in a database. I have a REST endpoint that delivers the data I need, but I can't figure out how to load the values before the app gets automatically bootstrapped.

I cannot modify the application to a manual-bootstrapping process. Typically a resolve would be used upon navigation, but I have other components (like modals) that use the constants that aren't necessarily part of any route.

What would be ideal would be some sort of "resolve", but at the application layer. I do have the ability to load npm and bower packages, but anything that changes to a 'manual' bootstrapping method isn't allowed.

Comment: You could have a root state with a resolve for all your values

Comment: @NewDev - that's not a bad idea. Right now only one state requires the constants so I am making the service call to the load the constants in the resolve section of my route... and since all of my modals, etc that use the constants can only be called from my one-state, there won't be any issue. I run the risk of the app expanding and those modals being called from somewhere else and not having the constants loaded yet, but I'll cross that bridge when I get there.

It seems the only real way to have things resolve before the app starts is to not automatically bootstrap the app.

Answer (score 0):

In that case I can recommend you to use a $rootScope. I don't understand very well your needs, but everything that is stored in $rootScope will be available in all views. Just fill it with your REST service inside the first or main view of your app. Although, it is important to understand that if you refresh you page, the $rootScope will be as well refreshed, this is, all of your REST calls will be launched again. (Navigating inside angular views is NOT refreshing the page unless you ask for it using window.reload() or similar; it is just the same page with a new controller)

To avoid this last behavior (page refresh) you could also use local Storage, which is basically a small amount of memory inside your browser where you can save any data that you want to keep regardless of your page refreshes. I used in one of my projects this library: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

It was useful for saving permanent stuff until user logs out.

Hope it helps! And sorry if I am answering something not useful for you
Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my issue. The issue I have is delaying the app from moving to the first view BEFORE the constants are loaded from the rest service. Having access to the data once it's loaded isn't an issue -- once the data has been loaded I have it available in an angular-service for whoever wants it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way to effectively load some values from a service prior to the app starting is to make the service-call to and then manually bootstrap the app. The idea of an app-wide "resolve" doesn't seem to exist.